# Understanding IN Statement in awk

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, if-statement, awk

I have the problem to understand the in statement in bash... First of all heres the code:

```
#! /bin/bash

dns=()
while read line; do
  up=$(nslookup $line | awk -F ': ' 'NR==6 {print $2} ')
  dns+=($up)
done < dns.blacklist.txt.txt

awk '{if( $1 in dns ) print $1 " Blacklisted"; else print $1}' thttpd2.log
```

So `thttp2.log` is just a list of IPs, while nslookup is getting the IP of hostnames (for blacklist puposes). So now I want to check if the IP that connected in the log, was on the blacklist, in the code in the `dns` array.

All IPs and lookups from `nslookup` are good: Dns=81.169.145.82 192.0.3.45 and awk $1=81.169.145.82 . So how can I check in the awk statement at the lower part, if $1 is in dns?

I've been trying for half a day now... I am pretty sure I have not understood "in" so can someone please give me at least a tip?

PS: Current result is just:

```
81.169.145.82
81.169.145.82
81.169.145.82
192.0.3.45
```

Goal:

```
81.169.145.82 Blacklisted
81.169.145.82 Blacklisted
81.169.145.82 Blacklisted
192.0.3.45
```

Comment: In your example `dns` is a bash array. `awk` is a program running from a (`bash`) `shell`. You cannot access directly the contents of a `bash` array from inside `awk`, the same way you cannot access and use a bash variable, as is, inside a python program.

Comment: Also, you write a `bash` loop to read the contents of a text file into an array, and your intention is to use this content as input for `awk`. While the ideal input for `awk` is a file, and you have that file already, so you have to give two file arguments to `awk` and do anything inside there.

Comment: ...having said that, the `in` statement ( is `awk` and not `bash`) is similar to python. You can say `for (i in a)` or `if (i in a)` but `a` should be an `awk` array, not a `bash` one,

Comment: @thanasisp So now I am transferring my array to awk to an array named a, but still no success?
`awk -v A="${dns[0]}" 'BEGIN {c=split(A,a)}' | awk '{if( $1 in a ) print $1 " blacklisted"; else print $1}' thttpd2.log`

Comment: `${dns[0]}` is only the first element of the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems better to use the output of your `while` loop as `awk` input, there is no reason to use in the middle a `bash` array, `awk` prefers a stream than any `bash` variables.

So, you produce a stream of ips reading your `blacklist.txt` file and parsing the `nslookup` output. I see that part as a black box in my answer, I assume you get good results and want to run your logic with the other file. Also it is not efficient to run one `nslookup` and one `awk` per line, in case of a large input, but I don't know what you do in that part, I leave it as is.

```
while read -r line; do
    nslookup "$line" | awk -F ': ' 'NR==6 {print $2}'
done < blacklist.txt | awk 'FNR==NR {dns[$0]; next}
                       {print ($1 in dns)? $1 " Blacklisted": $1}' - thttpd2.log
```

You could also give directly the blacklist file to `awk`, and inside `awk` to have a call to the external `bash` command you use. But I think it is simpler like this.

Answer (score 1):

> So how can I check in the awk statement at the lower part, if $1 is in dns?

`awk` is not shell and shell is not `awk`. Shell variable is unrelated to any `awk` variable and `awk` variables are unrelated to shell. `awk` is a separate program with separate syntax unrelated to shell and shell is a separate program with it's own syntax unrelated to `awk`.

The [construct `subscript in array`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#index-in-operator) is part of `awk` syntax to check if in `awk` the subscript *subscript* is one of subscripts inside `awk` array *array*. It's unrelated to shell variables and bash arrays. Note that subscript is not value of the element, it's the index. "array[subscript]=value"

> Understanding IN - Statement in Linux bash

The `in` in bash shell is used only as a keyword in `case` statement:

```
case something in
pattern) ;;
esac
```

It's usage is unrelated to `awk` usage, because shell is not `awk`.

> please give me at least a tip?

First read the input into `awk` as subscripts of array `dns`. After that, you may use the awk construct `something in dns` to check if something is a subscript of an array.

Answer (score 0):

You already got answers explaining what `in` means but also - since `nslookup` can read a list of domain names from stdin:

```
$ cat dns.blacklist.txt.txt
google.com
yahoo.com

$ nslookup < dns.blacklist.txt.txt
Default Server:  cdns01.foo.net
Address:  2222:555:beef::1

> Server:  cdns01.foo.net
Address:  2222:555:beef::1

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    google.com
Addresses:  2607:f8b0:4009:804::200e
          172.217.9.78

> Server:  cdns01.foo.net
Address:  2222:555:beef::1

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    yahoo.com
Addresses:  2001:4998:44:3507::8000
          2001:4998:124:1507::f001
          2001:4998:124:1507::f000
          2001:4998:44:3507::8001
          2001:4998:24:120d::1:1
          2001:4998:24:120d::1:0
          98.137.11.163
          74.6.143.25
          74.6.231.21
          98.137.11.164
          74.6.143.26
          74.6.231.20
```

you don't need to wrap anything in a shell loop, e.g. (untested):

```
nslookup < dns.blacklist.txt.txt |
awk '
    NR==FNR {
        if ( sub(/^Addresses:/,"") ) { inAddrs=1 }
        if ( inAddrs ) {
            if ( NF ) { dns[$1] }
            else { inAddrs=0 }
        }
        next
    }
    { print $1, ($1 in dns ? "Blacklisted" : "" }
' - thttpd2.log
```

Note that `nslookup` can output a list of IP addresses for a given domain, not just 1 as your existing script expects, and the above script will accommodate that.